# .NET 3.5 - Is there a SOAP Parser in the framework

Tags: parsing, .net-3.5, soap

Are there any SOAP parser classes within the .NET 3.5 framework?

In summary I have a string that contains a SOAP message, I need to be able to parse out various elements of the Envelope and also extract the Body etc.  At the moment I am doing this with xpaths.  This works but if there is a better way of doing it I am all ears.

Comment: Did you try the SoapFormatter (or because it is deprecated the BinaryFormatter)?

Comment: SoapFormatter has nothing to do with Soap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't believe there is any general-purpose SOAP parser in .NET.

I would either continue working with XPATH, or else use LINQ to XML. You may find it much easier than simple XPATH.